# MDX: ALL level value is not coming correctly when i use TopCount

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, olap-cube

I have a problem with the following query. It is returning ALL level value for the Agent dimension wrongly. My requirement is to get the ALL level value as sum of all the values selected for the TOPCOUNT function. Thanks.

```
WITH 
  SET [0] AS 
    {
      {
        [Sum Assured Bucket].[Sum Assured Bucket].[Sum Assured Bucket].[> 1200000]
       ,[Sum Assured Bucket].[Sum Assured Bucket].[Sum Assured Bucket].[> 1200000].Children
      }
    } 
  SET [1] AS 
    {
      {
        [Period].[Period].[Year].[2012]
       ,[Period].[Period].[Year].[2012].Children
      }
    } 
  SET [Agent_Agent_Agent_1_ADV] AS 
    {
      TopCount
      (
        Order
        (
          {AddCalculatedMembers([Agent].[Agent].[Agent])}
         ,[Measures].[Count Of Leads]
         ,BDESC
        )
       ,5
       ,[Measures].[Count Of Leads]
      )
    } 
  SET [Agent_Agent_Agent_1_ADV_VISULATOTAL] AS 
    VisualTotals([Agent_Agent_Agent_1_ADV]) 
  SET [HIDDEN_TOTAL_0] AS 
    VisualTotals([Agent_Agent_Agent_1]) 
  SET [Agent_Agent_Agent_1] AS 
    {
      {[Agent].[Agent].[All]}
     ,Order
      (
        {
          AddCalculatedMembers
          (
            Intersect
            (
              [Agent_Agent_Agent_1_ADV_VISULATOTAL]
             ,AddCalculatedMembers([Agent].[Agent].[Agent])
            )
          )
        }
       ,[Measures].[Count Of Leads]
       ,BDESC
      )
    } 
  SET [HIDDEN_TOTAL_1] AS 
    VisualTotals([Sum Assured Bucket_Sum Assured Bucket_Sum Assured Bucket_1]) 
  SET [HIDDEN_TOTAL_2] AS 
    VisualTotals([0]) 
  SET [Sum Assured Bucket_Sum Assured Bucket_Sum Assured Bucket_1] AS 
    {
      {[Sum Assured Bucket].[Sum Assured Bucket].[All]}
     ,Hierarchize
      (
        Intersect
        (
          [0]
         ,AddCalculatedMembers
          (
            [Sum Assured Bucket].[Sum Assured Bucket].[Sum Assured Bucket]
          )
        )
      )
    } 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      {[Agent].[Agent].[All]}
     ,Order
      (
        {
          AddCalculatedMembers
          (
            Intersect
            (
              VisualTotals
              (
                {
                  TopCount
                  (
                    Order
                    (
                      {AddCalculatedMembers([Agent].[Agent].[Agent])}
                     ,[Measures].[Count Of Leads]
                     ,BDESC
                    )
                   ,5
                   ,[Measures].[Count Of Leads]
                  )
                }
              )
             ,AddCalculatedMembers([Agent].[Agent].[Agent])
            )
          )
        }
       ,[Measures].[Count Of Leads]
       ,BDESC
      )
    }
  DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME  ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
    [Sum Assured Bucket_Sum Assured Bucket_Sum Assured Bucket_1]
  DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME  ON 1
 ,{[MEASURES].[Count Of Leads]} ON 2
FROM [New Policy Analysis];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a specific member in your cube: `[Agent].[Agent].[All]` it will not be equal to the result of your expression that uses `TopCount`.

You could create a calculated member that Aggregates or Sums the topCount set:

```
...
SET [Agent_Agent_Agent_1_ADV] AS 
    {
      TopCount
      (
        Order
        (
          {AddCalculatedMembers([Agent].[Agent].[Agent])}
         ,[Measures].[Count Of Leads]
         ,BDESC
        )
       ,5
       ,[Measures].[Count Of Leads]
      )
    } 
MEMBER [Agent].[Agent].[All_new] AS  
   Aggregate([Agent_Agent_Agent_1_ADV]) //<<<<Sum([Agent_Agent_Agent_1_ADV])
...
...
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      {[Agent].[Agent].[All_new]}  //<<<<
     ,Order
      (
        {
...
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But, it did not work for me. It worked after moving VISULATOTALS to SELECT part. Previously, I have been using VISULATOTALS as part of SET.